# How to convert Drawing.FontFamily to Media.FontFamily

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I would like to use a `Media.FontFamily` to change a TextBox (WPF Element) font.

First I use a `Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection`, and load a custom font with 
`AddMemoryFont(IntPtr, int)` function.
I only have the font in binary data, which is not installed the computer. (The font is embedded in a project's resources, but not in the same project).

With this method, I only have a `Drawing.FontFamily`. I'm looking for a solution, and I wonder if it is possible to solve the problem with these ideas or others :

Is it possible to directly convert a `Drawing.FontFamily` to `Media.FontFamily` ?
Maybe can we create a Media.FontFamily from binary data ?
Or is there a way to use a `Drawing.FontFamily` in to change a TextBox's font ?

Comment: This is an XY question.  Just drop the dependency on PrivateFontCollection and use the [resource directly](http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx).

Comment: The resource is not in the same project. The only can get it with a byte[].